# How do you call a function with parameters in a .then function in a JavaScript promise string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, aws-lambda, bluebird

I am converting my AWS lambda functions, written in node.js, to use promises instead of callbacks.  I'm wrapping all of my functions in the handler with the handler code.  I'm trying to break out simple functions so I can have as flat a promise chain as possible in the handler code.

I'm stuck at one point where I have a .then() that returns a value that I need to pass to one of my functions, which has been promisified, along with other parameters.  I have searched high & low but can't find an example of the syntax to do this.  I'm not even sure what I'm doing is the right thing at all.  All of the articles I've found explain simple promise chains that only return a value through the .then() method.  None that then pass it into another promisified function.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var bbPromise = require("./node_modules/bluebird");
var AWS = require("./node_modules/aws-promised");
var rp = require("./node_modules/request-promise");
var moment = require('./node_modules/moment.js');
var dynamodb = new AWS.dynamoDb();

exports.handler = function(event, context) { 
    "use-strict"; 

    // This gets a token that will be used as a parameter for a request
    function getToken(params){
        return rp.post({
            url: "https://api.something.com/oauth2/token",
            followRedirects: true,
            form: params,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function(body){
            return JSON.parse(body).access_token;
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("could not get token: "+error);
        });
    }

    function getData(userId, db, token){ 
        var qParams = {
            // params that will get one record 
        };
        return dynamodb.queryPromised(qParams)
        .then(function (data){
            var start_date = // did some date manipulation on data to get this value
            // Request records, passing the token in the header
            var url = "https://api.something.com/data/?db="+db+"&start_date="+start_date;
            var headers = {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Authorization':'Bearer '+token
            };
            tokenParams = {all the parameters};
            rp.get({
                url:url, 
                qs:tokenParams, 
                headers:headers, 
                followRedirect: true
            }).then(function(body){
                return body;
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log("could not get data: "+error);
            });
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Final Catch - getData failed: "+error);
        });
    }

    // THIS IS WHERE THE HANDLER CODE STARTS

    // Get an array of all userIds then get their data
    dynamodb.scanPromised({
        // params that will get the user Ids
    }).then(function(users){
        for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
            userId = // the value from the user record;        
            // Request a token
            var tokenParams = {an object of params};
            getToken(tokenParams)
            .then(function(token){
            ///////////// THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP /////////////////
            /* Is there a way to pass getData the token within the .then() so I don't have a nested promise? */
                getData(userId, users[i].dbName, token)

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }).catch(function (e){
                console.log("caught an error");
            });
        }
    }).catch(function (e){
        console.log("caught an error");
    });
};
```

Comment: You are using a loop there. You'll *need* to nest. There's nothing wrong with that either.

Comment: What's wrong with just doing: `getData(userId, users[i].dbName, token).then(function (data) { /* handle the data here */ })`?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to put that getData call inside the previous .then().

Comment: I think you will find it a lot easier to get started with promises if you use something like `co` and generators https://www.npmjs.com/package/co

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Promise.all()`, `.then()`, `Function.prototype.bind()`; `return` `rp.get()` from `getData()`

```
 return Promise.all(users.map(function(user) {
   userId = // the value from the user record;        
     // Request a token
     var tokenParams = {
       an object of params
     };
   return getToken(tokenParams)
     .then(getData.bind(null, userId, user.dbName))
     .catch(function(e) {
       console.log("caught an error");
       throw e
     });
 }))
```

Comment: this answer addresses the main issue however there is another flow in the original question: don't forget to ```return rp.get```

Comment: This answer may be what I'm looking for but I'm a little confused.  Will this syntax automatically pass the token returned by getToken into getData?  And if so, as what parameter?  Would it take the place of the null param?

Comment: @user3353762 Yes. As last parameter to `getData()`

Comment: I was not able to make this work.  When I pass null as the first parameter, then within getData, userId gets the null value, dbName gets the userId value, and token is undefined.  If I pass "token" into getData as the 3rd parameter, it is still undefined.  I'm still confused as to how to pass the return value from getToken into getData within the .then parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

When using a promise, your code should look more like this.

```
when.try(() => {
    return api.some_api_call
})
.then((results) => {
    const whatIAmLookingFor = {
        data: results.data
    };

    someFunction(whatIAmLookingFor);
})
.then(() => {
    return api.some_other_api_call
})
.then((results) => {
    const whatIAmLookingFor = {
        data: results.data
    };

    someOtherFunction(whatIAmLookingFor); 
.catch(() => {
    console.log('oh no!');
})
});
```

Comment: Nesting of promises is totally allowed and often totally necessary. For example, above, if `api.some_other_api_call()` returns a promise, its eventual value (or error) would be delivered to the following `.then()`'s callback on settlement. The promise resolution procedure in the [Promises/A+ specification](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) is specifically designed for this. Look around at a few examples - you will find nested promises everywhere.