# ES6 Promise Sequence, XHR for Token then XHR Again

Tags: javascript

I need to do a promise sequence.  I'd like to use a standards based approach (ES6?).  What's the best way to achieve this?  `getToken()` and `httpReq()` return promises, `clock.now` simply returns the unix timestamp of now.  My code looks something like below now (simplified/condensed).  I understand I need to flatten the promise chain with a single catch...  Can someone illustrate a clean, readable, non-clever, ES6 way?

```
// we don't have a good token so we need to get one first, then GET the resource.
getToken(host, port, auth).then(function(token) {

  httpReq(method, host, port, path, token).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }, function(status) {
    console.log(status);
  });


}, function(status) {
  console.log(status);
});
```

Comment: See also [How do you call a function with parameters in a .then function in a JavaScript promise string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538284/how-do-you-call-a-function-with-parameters-in-a-then-function-in-a-javascript-p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. Here's how I'd do it:

```
getToken(host, port, auth) // Promise for token
  .then(token => httpReq(method, host, post, path, token)) // Promise for data, using token
  .then(data => console.log(data)) // final step
  .catch(err => console.error(err)); // error handling for all steps in the chain
```

And without the arrow functions:

```
getToken(host, port, auth)
  .then(function(token) { return httpReq(method, host, post, path, token); })
  .then(function(data) { return console.log(data); }) // not strictly necessary. But
                                                      // strictly equivalent to above
  .catch(function(err) { return console.log(err); });
```

Few things to note:

- Don't nest `.then()` clauses. Instead, return a Promise from the first `.then()` clause, and continue the chain outside.
- When using Promises, make sure to always *return* a Promise. Never leave a `.then()` clause without a return value, and never leave a function that has Promises without a return value.
- Using arrow functions makes both points above easy.

Comment: I meant, his attempt looked very close to correct, in my eyes. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Interesting noting the possible different perspectives of users, including moderators, when viewing Question and Answer. From vantage here, appeared as though you were referencing the user image at Question.

Comment: thank you.  Any chance you could show it without the arrows?

Comment: @RonRoyston Sure thing